# How can I add additional payment information in admin order view page during order creation with magento SOAP(V2) service API?

Tags: web-services, magento, soap

I am trying to add extra data in **Payment Information** section like ***Bank Name***: xxxxx and ***Account Number***: xxxxx. But I don't know the exact operation to add the extra data. The steps I followed:

Added two params (param1, param2) in the file `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/wsdl.xml` :

```
<message name="shoppingCartPaymentMethodRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="quoteId" type="xsd:int"/>
    <part name="method" type="typens:shoppingCartPaymentMethodEntity"/>
    <part name="storeId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="param1" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="param2" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
```

Also added for WS-I complience. file : `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/wsi.xml`

```
<xsd:element name="shoppingCartPaymentMethodRequestParam">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="quoteId" type="xsd:int" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="paymentData" type="typens:shoppingCartPaymentMethodEntity" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="store" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="param1" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="param2" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Here I tried to catch the params like this but didnt get any value.
file name: `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart/Payment/Api.php`

```
public function setPaymentMethod($quoteId, $paymentData, $store = null, $param1, $param2)
{
    Mage::log($param1);
    Mage::log($param2);
    // extra code
}
```

Here is my client code `order-test.php`:

```
<?php
$user = 'user';
$password = '123456789';
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
    $sessionId = $proxy->login($user, $password);    

    // extra codes

    $paymentMethod =  array(
        'method' => 'checkmo',
        // also tried here passing two params (param1, param2)   
    );
     // add payment method
    $proxy->shoppingCartPaymentMethod($sessionId, $cartId, $paymentMethod, null, $param1, $param2);    
     // place the order
    $orderId = $proxy->shoppingCartOrder($sessionId, $cartId, null, null);    
    var_dump($orderId);
?>
```

Can anybody help on this topic ?
Thank You.

**Note:** Without passing extra parameters its working fine.